# File Sync to Nitrous IO server

Tags: nitrousio

I am attempting to use the MAC version of Nitrous Desktop (v1.02) such that I can connect my Nitrous IO ~/workspace to my Nitrous directory on my MAC. Currently I have an application in ~/workspace that I have been syncing through git so that I can use Sublime to edit locally, but I want to get Nitrous Desktop working.

Everything in the app is green: File Sync is green and says Monitoring, Port Forwarding works great, all other buttons work well. Problem is that the Nitrous directory on my local mac never updates with what is on the Nitrous IO server. As a test I tried to create a directory and inserted a file under Nitrous, but it also doesn't sync to the server.

Git works fine for me, but if anyone knows what I am doing wrong to get file sync to work, please let me know.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [Nitrous Desktop](http://help.nitrous.io/nitrous-desktop/) will sync files that are found within `~/workspace/`, and files will be monitored locally and uploaded when changed. As of Jan 24, polling is not supported, so you will need to click `Sync Now` within the Mac app if you are making changes on the server end (Nitrous box).

Comment: Thanks for the response gman. I got the sync to work with my Mac Air, but not for iMac. Did not have to Sync Now when it was the first time on Mac Air, but will use your advice when I update directly to the server. Again thanks!